# In datadog how can I do a log search for an event that doesn't contain a column/field?

Tags: datadog

In datadog how can I do a log search for an event that doesn't contain a column/field?
For example I want to omit the field monolith_ex and I tried:
`-@monolith_ex:"*"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can do this with:
`-@monolith_ex:*`